# Is every symmetric bilinear form on a Hilbert space a weighted inner product?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form

Is every symmetric bilinear form on a Hilbert space a weighted inner product?
i.e. can I write that $b(u,v) = (wu,v)_H$ for all $u, v \in H$?
I am not sure about this. Maybe something to do with Riesz theorem..

Answer (score 2):

Since you're interested in bilinear forms, I'll assume you're working with a real Hilbert space $H$; in the complex case, replace "bilinear" with "sesquilinear."

1. First, suppose that you have a *bounded* bilinear form $b$, so that there exists some constant $C \geq 0$ such that $b(u,v) \leq C\|u\|\|v\|$ for all $u$, $v \in H$. Then for all $u \in H$, $b(u,\cdot)$ defines a bounded linear functional on $H$ (why?), so that by the Riesz theorem, $b(u,\cdot) = (w(u),\cdot)_H$ for a unique $w(u) \in H$; check (how?) that $u \mapsto w(u)$ defines a bounded linear operator on $H$.
2. Now, suppose in addition that $b$ is symmetric. Check that $w$ is therefore self-adjoint. In fact, $b$ is symmetric if and only if $w$ is self-adjoint (why?).
3. Finally, suppose in addition that $b$ is positive-definite, i.e., $b(u,u) > 0$ for all $u \neq 0$. Check, then, that $w$ is therefore positive-definite, so that $b$ is indeed a weighted inner product. In fact, $b$ is positive-definite (and thus a weighted inner product) if and only if $w$ is positive definite (why?).

Throughout all this, all you really need is to remember what the Riesz theorem says, and what it means for an operator to be self-adjoint and positive-definite. In particular, observe the role (indeed, necessity and sufficiency) of the hypotheses of boundedness, symmetry (which you already had), and positive-definiteness.

Comment: Is inner product always sesquilinear in Hilbert space?

Comment: After showing (1-3), can you now state the the bilinear form is sesquilinear? I am wondering if it is wrong to assume that the operator is bilinear when it belongs to the Hilbert space. Should we directly assume that the operator is sesquilinear, and directly showing it too; instead of the bilinear assumption?

Comment: Can this mapping, $u \mapsto w(u)$ be surjective? I think it has to be surjective for the Hilbert space. But have you showed the surjectivity?