# Show that $l_{2}(J)$ is Hilbert Space for Countably Infinite Set?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, infinity

The inner product is

\begin{equation*}
\langle u, v \rangle = \sum\limits_{j \in J} u_{j} \overline{v_{j}}
\end{equation*}
where $u,v$ are vectors and $J$ is the countably infinite set $J = \mathbb{N}$.

### New try for $J = \mathbb{N}$

For $k,t \in \mathbb{N}$, consider $e_{k}, e_{t} \in l_{p}$. 
By the parallegrom law, we have for $1 \leq p < \infty$ 
\begin{equation*}
\| e_{k} + e_{t} \|_{p}^{2} + \| e_{k} - e_{t} \|_{p}^{2} =
2 \Big( \| e_{k} \|_{p}^{2} + \| e_{t} \|_{p}^{2} \Big),
\end{equation*}
so $2^{2/p} + 2^{2/p} = 2^{2}$, $2^{1+2/p} = 2^{2}$, i.e. $p = 2$. 
So $(l^{2}, \| \cdot \|)$ is a Hilbert space. $\square$

Source

- Exercises in Functional Analysis, Constantin Costara and Dumitru Popa

I think the use of parallegrom theorem is convenient. One possibility is with Cauchy-Schwarz directly. Probably more rigorous proofs still?

### [depreciated; wrong because $J = \mathbb{C}^{n}$ i.e. countably finite set]

**Conjugate symmetric**. 
The inner product is conjugate symmetric:
\begin{equation*}
    (\forall u,v \in J) \, \langle u, v \rangle = \overline{v, u}. 
\end{equation*}

**Linearity in one of the arguments**. 
The inner product satisfies the properties where it is linear in the first variable:

- Positive-definite: $(\forall u \in J) \, \langle u, u \rangle \geq 0$; $\langle u, u \rangle = 0$ iff $u = 0.$
- Distributive law: $(\forall u,v,h \in J) \langle u + h, v \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle + \langle h, v \rangle$.
- Homegenous under scaling for each variable: $(\forall c \in \mathbb{C}) \, (\forall u,v \in J), \, \langle c u, v \rangle = c \langle u,v \rangle = \langle u, c v \rangle$.

Assume there is a bounded bilinear form $b$:
\begin{equation*}
    \exists C \geq \quad b(u,v) \leq C \|u\| \|v\| \, \forall u,v \in J. 
\end{equation*} 
For all $u \in J$, $b(u, \cdot)$ defines a bounded linear functional $J$, 
so that the Riesz theorem implies $b(u,\cdot) = (w(u), \cdot)_{J}$ for a unique $w(u) \in J$. $u : w(J \to J')$ defines a bounded linear operator on $J$ where $J'$ is a space of continuous linear functionals. Riesz theorem says what it means for an operator to be self-adjoint and positive-definite, when the operator is bounded, symmetric and positive-definite. 
The mapping is also surjective because $\forall u \in J, \exists w(u) \in J'$ such that $u = w(u)$. 
If the mapping is surjective, it must a Hilbert space.

Note $b$ is symmetric iff $w$ is self-adjoint. 
Recall that $b$ is positive-definite, so $b$ is a weighted inner product. 
$b$ is positive-definite and thus a weighted inner product iff $w$ is positive definite.
So the bilinear form is sesquilinear:
\begin{equation*}
(\forall c \in \mathbb{C}) \, (\forall u,v \in J) \, \overline{ \langle u,v \rangle } = \langle v,u \rangle \Rightarrow \langle u, c v \rangle = \bar{c} \langle u,v \rangle.
\end{equation*}
where the last three points imply that the inner product is conjugate symmetric in the second variable:
\begin{equation*}
(\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C})\, (\forall u,v,h \in J) \, 
\langle h, \alpha u + \beta v \rangle 
= \bar{\alpha}\langle h, u \rangle + \bar{\beta} \langle h, v \rangle.
\end{equation*}

The $l_{2}(J)$ is Hilbert space with the inner product. $\square$

Sources

- Hilbert spaces definition: [555notes5.ps_pages.pdf](https://www.google.lv/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwii4rzMw5zIAhWBqnIKHYP4AJk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.washington.edu%2F~greenbau%2FMath_555%2FCourse_Notes%2F555notes5.ps_pages.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEcGnY5vL9URRIV7y_umVOi6V3X4g)
- Hilbert Space and Completeness: [lec_11.pdf](https://www.google.lv/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwiRsbPYw5zIAhWjg3IKHfy3CEw&url=http%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Fmathematics%2F18-103-fourier-analysis-theory-and-applications-spring-2004%2Flecture-notes%2Flec_11.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHfOpHtkW9ebUYvqxaSHg7rgRvTBw&bvm=bv.103627116,d.bGQ)
- [Is every symmetric bilinear form on a Hilbert space a weighted inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/385390/17474)

---

How can you show rigorously that $l_{2}(J)$ is Hilbert space for the countably infinite set $J$ with the inner product?

Comment: Do they actually ask you to show that this function is an inner product?  It sounds like they might be expecting you to assume it and move forward.

Comment: It should not be necessary to use Riesz's theorem here.

Comment: If you assume homogeneity in both components, it is stricter than what people usually understand as inner product of a complex linear space

Comment: Do you have an other norm on $J$ than the one induced by the inner product? You don't have to show that the inner product is continuous w.r.t. the norm it induced

Comment: Also: you seem to denote the inner space by $J$ but also the index set by $J$.

Comment: Is $J$ finite or not? If not, what is the definition of the sum? Then, basically copy the proof that $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: in case $J$ is finite, it is the usual one. I asked in case $J$ is not finite. Just copy the proof for $\mathbb C^n$ then

Comment: Do you know measure theory? If yes: the sum is actually the integral w.r.t. The counting measure on $J$. If no: find the definition given in course. It should include the result that you may select an enumeration $j_1, j_2, \dotsc$ of $J$. Thus, you may assume $J=\mathbb N$ w.l.o.g. If you don't know that $\ell_2$ is an inner product space, write the series as limit of partial sums and apply some limit argument.

Comment: The vector space $\ell^2(J)$ with the above inner product is a Hilbert space regardless of the cardinality of $J$. I don't think it's very enlightening to use some assumptions on the cardinality in the proof.

Comment: @MaoWao: It is true, but I just want to avoid typing out a week worth lecture on integration theory in measure space :)

Comment: @Masi. You need to show some effort. It is unlikely that anybody want to do your homework for you.

Comment: @user251257: I see your point. But I didn't mean to prove it for an arbitrary measure space as that's technically much harder. I just meant that the proof for the counting measure on an uncountable set is the same as for a countable set if you spell it out correctly.

Comment: I included a new proposal for the answer based on Parallegrom law.